# Libgdx box2d body overlaps with sprite

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, box2d

I have been puzzling my mind with the code and I've made a huge amount of progress from not doing pixel to meter to now having a body and sprite almost in line however ive reached another point where i can't seem to figure out where I have gone wrong. [image]

As you can see from the image the body is off from the actual sprite, I have a hunch that it might be origin as it the difference is very slight but I can't seem to work out how to get it in line.

My Create method

```
    public class Physics1 extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
SpriteBatch batch;
Sprite sprite;
Texture img;
World world;
Body body;
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
Matrix4 debugMatrix;
OrthographicCamera camera;
Vector2 bodyOrigin;


float torque = 0.0f;
boolean drawSprite = true;

final float PIXELS_TO_METERS = 100f;

final float WORLD_WIDTH =100;
final float WORLD_HEIGHT=100;


@Override
public void create() {

    Assets.instance.init(new AssetManager());
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    bodyOrigin = new Vector2();

    sprite = new Sprite();
    sprite.setRegion(Assets.instance.tyre.tyre);
    sprite.setSize(12,12);
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);




    sprite.setPosition(50-sprite.getWidth()/2,25);

    Gdx.app.log("Physics1", "Sprite positions"+ -sprite.getWidth()/2+ " ,"+ -sprite.getHeight()/2);

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0f),true);

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    BodyEditorLoader load = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("levels/pittstop.json"));

    bodyDef.position.set(sprite.getX()/PIXELS_TO_METERS,sprite.getY()/PIXELS_TO_METERS);


    Gdx.app.log("Physics1", "Body positions calculations"+ sprite.getX() +" "+ sprite.getWidth()/2);

    Gdx.app.log("Physics1", "Body positions"+ bodyDef.position);
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

    fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;


    fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;


    float scale =0.2f;

    load.attachFixture(body, "tyre", fixtureDef, scale);
    Gdx.app.log("Physics1"," Orgin of body" +load.getOrigin("tyre", scale).cpy());
    bodyOrigin = load.getOrigin("tyre", scale).cpy();

    body.setUserData("tyre");


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(WORLD_WIDTH,WORLD_HEIGHT);
    Gdx.app.log("Physics1", "camera "+ camera.viewportWidth+" "+camera.viewportHeight);

    camera.position.set(WORLD_WIDTH / 2f, WORLD_HEIGHT / 2f, 0);
    Gdx.app.log("Physics1", "camera "+ camera.viewportWidth+" "+camera.viewportHeight);

}
```

My render method

```
    public void render() {
    camera.update();
    world.step(1f/60f, 6, 2);

    body.applyTorque(torque,true);

    sprite.setPosition((body.getPosition().x * PIXELS_TO_METERS), 
            (body.getPosition().y * PIXELS_TO_METERS))
             ;

    sprite.setRotation((float)Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle()));

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    debugMatrix = batch.getProjectionMatrix().cpy().scale(PIXELS_TO_METERS, 
                  PIXELS_TO_METERS, 0);

    batch.begin();


    if(drawSprite)
        batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(),bodyOrigin.x,
                   bodyOrigin.y,
            sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight(),sprite.getScaleX(),sprite.
                            getScaleY(),sprite.getRotation());


    batch.end();

    debugRenderer.render(world, debugMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

False alarm, turns out in physics editor you have the opportunity to change the origin of the body you are drawing up, just by clicking around I was able to move the origin to the centre and there you have it.

[image]